# Carrying pets in commercial international airlines

Tags: airlines, pets

Do commercial international airlines allow passengers to carry pets like cats and dogs?

If yes, can we have a database of those commercial airlines that allow passengers to carry pets?

If no, why?

Example: Lufthansa, Qatar Airways, Singapore airlines, British Airways, Cathay Pacific, etc.

Comment: What do you mean? In cabin or just transport in pressurized cargo? And what kind of answer to you expect? Travel stackexchange may be more relevant on such questions (link on top right icon).

Comment: My daughter recently took her cat from the US to the Netherlands in a carrier in the cabin on KLM, so yes, they are allowed. Please be consider of those who may be allergic to pet dander...

Comment: I do not know why you edited in a link to a search to pet passports but it did not explain anything and might make existing answers invalid. So rolled back.

Answer (score 8):

This is **extremely variable** from one airline to another.

- **Some will not allow pets at all** (that's the case of EasyJet for instance, but there are probably a lot more).
- **Some will allow pets in the hold only.**

  This requires a crate meeting all regulations, especially its size which must be adapted for the pet following some very detailed rules, its safety, etc.

  In this case, the pet is considered as accompanied baggage (i.e. they are supposed to travel on the same plane as you -- see below for the distinction with "freight").

  As far as I know, this will always incur a fee.
- **Some will allow pets up to a certain size in the cabin, and larger ones in the hold only.**

  The size cut-off varies from airline to airline (I believe I've seen various values between 6 and 10 kg, container included).

  There is usually a requirement that the pet remain in the container and that the container be small enough to fit under the seat in front of you, so that restricts it to pretty small pets (cats and very small dogs).

  There will often be a fee as well, and you must usually declare your pet's presence on your booking.

There may be additional restrictions in either case:

- On the **type of pet** (cats and dogs but no other animals in the cabin, for instance) -- though some airlines like Qatar Airways allow falcons in the cabin, with specific rules
- Some **breeds** (especially dogs and cats with "flat faces", which suffer from breathing issues, and dogs considered dangerous) may not be allowed.
- There is often a **limit on the number of pets** (in total and/or per passenger)
- Pets need to be old enough, have the required vaccines...
- They may need a health certificate
- If travelling internationally, they must have a **pet passport**
- There are often **restrictions on flights with connections**
- You must be at the airport much earlier
- Some airlines will not allow pets in the cabin in premium classes
- There may be restrictions based on the aircraft type
- There may be restrictions on some routes
- And probably a lot more

The cost for adding a pet to your booking varies a lot depending on whether it travels in the cabin (where possible) or in the hold, the airline, the duration of the trip. I've seen fees of up to 400 euros per leg.

Some airlines will provide neither hold nor cabin options, but will tell you the pet should be sent as **freight** (IIRC that's the case of BA). While the physical conditions are the same as for travel in the hold (pet in a crate, hold at an adapted temperature, etc.), this means the pet will not necessarily travel on the plane as you, and the procedures are quite different (including where you drop off and pick up the animal: this may happen at cargo facilities rather than the passenger terminal).

On some airlines which do allow hold or cabin options for some pets but not all, the freight option may be the only alternative for other animals, notably the larger ones (horses...), the ones which need to be transported in water (dolphins, sharks...), but also sometimes dogs beyond a certain size.

Of course, the rules are usually quite **different for assistance pets**, though what is accepted as such varies a lot. In the US you can pass off nearly anything as an "emotional support animal" (I think I've seen stories about miniature horses). Elsewhere it's usually only guide dogs for people with sight deficiencies.

There are so many rules that I believe it's difficult to have an exhaustive list of which ones allow what. Your best option is to check the specific policies of the airlines you are interested in, this is nearly always detailed on their website, with sometimes a LOT of information.

#### Edit

Apparently 400 euros per leg for a long haul flight is on the cheap side of things. [This article from the New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2024/02/22/us/pet-animal-travel-costs-iag-cargo.html) mentions thousands or even tens of thousands in some cases.

Comment: (+1) Would be interesting to know how/if airlines consider passenger allergies when accepting pets on board. I recently travelled long haul in economy and there were at least 3 passengers with small dogs. Leaving aside the intermittent yapping and hygiene concerns during a long flight, I wondered what would happen if a fellow passenger was allergic.

Comment: @Traveller, my DIL is allergic to cats and had one sitting next to her on a (domestic US) flight home a couple of years back. The cabin staff did nothing despite her repeated requests to be moved away - even to the less comfortable, noisier back of the plane - to minimize her symptoms. She had 12 miserable hours. (Domestic flight from anywhere AK to anywhere continental other than SEA can easily be 12+ hours total travel time).

Comment: @Traveller Since airlines will in most cases not know in advance about such allergies, they certainly can't do anything preemptively until a passenger comes forward with the problem, most likely after having spotted the pet, and I doubt that at that point they would start telling passengers with pets not to board or to disembark. What they do exactly after that is probably a matter of airline policy. I think I've seen stories about nuts not being served an all on a flight because someone had a severe allergy, but at the other end they could also just say "sorry can't do anything". YMMV.

Comment: If travelling internationally, they must have a pet passport - Is a pet passport mandatory?

Comment: @PrashantAkerkar possibly depends on the combination of countries, but most often, yes. Not that a per passport is something you get from your vet, it’s not like a regular passport.

Comment: Emotional support animal rules in the US have tightened significantly in the last few years, several airlines no longer allow them at all

Comment: [Emotional support animals are not service animals](https://www.ada.gov/topics/service-animals/#about-service-animals) (and never have been)

Answer (score 4):

Most airlines allow passengers to bring pets. Usually, smaller animals and guide or assistance dogs are allowed in the cabin, while other animals must be transported in the cargo hold.

When it comes to international travel, bringing pets is however often restricted by customs or disease prevention regulations independent of what the airlines offer. The rules vary so much from country to country and will also depend on the type of animal, that it is impossible to give a complete list here. They may range from no restrictions at all, via mandatory vaccines, health inspections or quarantine to an unconditional import ban.