How people carry large dogs in the airplane cabin?
I need to fly my cat across the Atlantic (Lisbon to São Paulo). Every airliner I searched had similar requirements for the pet size and weight: 8-10kg, fitting in a bag with at most 28cm height.
He is a large cat. With the transport bag, he weights more than 10kg. He is overweight, but even after dieting down to the ideal BMI, he can't possibly stand comfortably in 28cm height carrier bag.
I don't even know if it is possible ship pets in the cargo hold in a 10h30m flight, but even if it is, last week there were many protests around Brazil after a dog that was supposed to fly for 2h was shipped to the wrong city, and eventually died. I am not willing to risk shipping him.
Yet we I see all over Instagram and the Internet people with large dogs, adult Golden Retrievers and such, traveling in the cabin, even seated on a passenger's seat.
How is that possible? How can I take my cat with me?

Can you link examples of such videos? Is it possible they are service dogs? Also, are they recent? Airlines used to be permissive about allowing dogs to fly as emotional support animals, but have cracked down in the last few years.

Also, domestic or short-haul flights within certain countries may have different rules from long-haul international.

Larger animals travelling in the cabin are nearly certainly assistance dogs. Other animals exceeding the limits for travelling in the cabin have to travel in a crate in the hold, if at all available. Or fly with Bark Air but routes and dates are very limited and prices extremely high.

Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/186505/30703

@jcaron That looks like a joke website (According to a recent national poll, 87% of table scraps are dropped by children. Unfortunately, the same poll shows that children are responsible for 100% of tail pulling. Therefore, we do not allow humans under the age of 126 (18 human years) on BARK Air.)

@gerrit they have taken the funny marketing approach, but I think they're actually serious about their service. Pretty niche market given the limited routes and very high prices, though.

The Queen Mary will carry pets.

Airlines have clear rules about this type of thing. Depending on size and weight the animal can either go as

Carry on in the cabin
Fly in a crate in the cargo hold but on the same flights as you: same as checked luggage
Need to be shipped as air cargo.

We have travelled with our large black Labrador retriever with option 2 across the Atlantic. It went fine without any problems. In fact, her travel crate become one of her favorite sleeping place even at home (we left it out for her to use as she wanted).

Yet we I see all over Instagram and the Internet people with large dogs, adult Golden Retrievers and such, traveling in the cabin, even seated on a passenger's seat.

It's social media, not reality. Rules around larger animals in the cabin are very strict and restricted to service animals. Airlines have been cracking down on this: no more service pigs allowed ! link

I am not willing to risk shipping him.

If you are not comfortable with your cat in the cargo hold travelling with you, than you either need to leave him behind or stay at home. Sorry.
This being said: The rules do vary a bit between airlines, so you can try to find the airline whose rules are the best for you and your cat. See for example Lufthansa's rules here: https://www.lufthansa.com/kr/en/travelling-with-animals
